# TypeError: object is not a function - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, protractor, pageobjects

I am trying to do a very simple test using Page Objects, but I stucked right away with "login.get is not a function" error.

I copy just a little part of code, because the rest are similar

```
//login_pageObject.js

let loginContainer = function() {

    this.get = function() {
        browser.get("https://www.test/login.html");
    };

module.exports = new loginContainer();
};


//login.js

let login = require('../page_objects/login_pageObject.js'); 
describe("login_logout autotests", () => {

    beforeEach(() => {
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    });

    fit("should navigate to the Login Page", () => {
        login.get();
    });
```

So, when I run it, I have a "login.get is not a function" error.
Where is mistake?

Comment: `module.exports` should be outside the function, last line of your file

Comment: ohMy! Exactly! Thank you so much! :)

Comment: Ah, cool if it solved your problem :) I have added this as an answer, please validate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`module.exports` should be outside the function, last line of your file